# Silverlight: Style for Custom Control in Same Project

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight application with a custom control `MyDataGrid` which is a `DataGrid` with some extra features.

This is part of the project in which it is used.  It also requires a custom style.  I can add the style to my style resource dictionary and set `TargetType="sdk:DataGrid"` which works.

However, my style relies on a property `MyProperty` specific to `MyDataGrid`, so a warning appears in the editor.  More importantly, the styles cannot be previewed in the designer.

They DO work when the code is run, however.

My question is: *Is there a way to pull in local controls to a resource dictionary, rather than creating a separate project, compiling it to a .dll, and pulling in that assembly?*

Thanks!

Comment: Have you defined a generic.xaml for your MyDataGrid class?

Comment: no?  Do you have any info on how I would go about making this work?  I can find some information about it, but not a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you made a custom control, but you haven't defined a default style for it.  Try the following:

1. In your project, add a folder at the root level called Themes.
2. In the Themes folder, add a ResourceDictionary named generic.xaml.
3. Add all of your MyDataGrid styles to generic.xaml.
4. Make sure one of the styles is an implicit style (using BasedOn is a great solution here).
5. In the default constructor for MyDataGrid, add the line `DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyDataGrid);`

If you want to access part of the style (which is defined in XAML) from code, you should name that XAML item as "PART_something".  The design tools understand the PART_* syntax plus that's an indication to library consumers that if you retemplate the control, you must define the required pieces prefixed with PART_.

Here are the basics on how to [define a custom control](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-a-Silverlight-Custom-Control-The-Basics.aspx).